# Browser Print Generation

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, browser

I use:

```
window.print();
```

to print documents.

Problem:

As you guys know that browsers automatically adds page's title, path on top of the print page and page number and date on footer of the page.

But the client has asked me to remove all those things from the page or change their color to white so that they are not visible.

Question:

Is it possible to remove those things from page generated by the browser?

(I suspect answer might be no but no sure; possibly this can be controlled :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a setting on the browser and can be turned on and off.

http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer.php

Only way to do this is via ActiveX for IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do something server side, you could create a PDF file which the user can then print. I've not seen how to this on the browser itself, although I'd be interested to see if anyone else has.